# iOS rearrange subviews after hide

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, subview, addsubview

I want to get the functionality of **GONE** like in **Android** in **iOS** that when I hide any view it will rearrange the other views and when I unhide it will again rearrange other views .. keeping in view that im using autolayout constraints in stroyboard.

Also obviously when I embed a `UIScrollview` it will rearrange and re define the `scrollview` height again according to visible views.

Any code help would be highly appreciated, im working in Swift, and want just when my app execute the line `myView.hidden = true` it will rearrange the uiviews.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: yes sure, suppose we have 3 views in a scrollview, I just hide 2nd view and now I want the third view to be in place of second view and obviously have some affect on scroll height also.. @AlekseyPotapov

Answer (score 0):

This will be done for you if `myView` is an arranged subview of a `UIStackView`.

[UIStackView Tutorial: Introducing Stack Views](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views)

> Stack views are fully compatible with the UIView animation engine. This means that animating the appearance/disappearance of an arranged subview, is as simple as toggling its hidden property inside an animation block ... In addition to animating the hidden property on views contained within the stack view, you can also animate properties on the stack view itself, such as alignment, distribution, spacing and even the axis.